# Computing average values in 0.4 sec. interval in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'cardoor' with accelerometer data:

```
Time          | dx        | dy
=====================================
1464684066.38 |  -2.090   |   -0.570
1464684066.45 | -2.150    |   -0.670
1464684066.48 | -2.090    |   -0.650
```

I'm trying to get a the average values of 'dx' and 'dy' using a 0.4 second interval from a 'Time' column.

So far I've got this mySQL to get the data with the interval, but it doesn't work for me, I mean it is too slow (I waited 30 min. for a table with 2 million rows).

I need to add 2 columns avg(dx) and avg(dy) which are average values for the last 0.4 seconds.

```
SELECT b.Time, AVG(dx), AVG(dy)
FROM cardoor b LEFT JOIN cardoor p
ON p.Time BETWEEN b.Time-0.4 AND b.Time
GROUP BY b.Time
```

I am happy to consider suggestions outside of MySQL if more appropriate.

Comment: Exactly what type of average are you trying to get - it looks like your query will give an average for each of the two million entries - the averages being within the 0.4second time - resulting in effectively a rolling average. This means your need to compare 2million records with 2million records - hence slow. If you want to split the 2million records into 0.4second blocks and take the average of those - returning far fewer than 2million records - then you could probably speed things up significantly.

Comment: I have tried next query: [code]select AVG(dx),  from_unixtime(ROUND(Time / (60*0.00666)) * 60 * 0.00666) as rounded_time
from auto.cardoor1
group by rounded_time[/code] and got an average result for 1 sec. (So, it doesn't work for less than 1sec.) . And time I got in format like '20/01/2016 18:54:44', but I need Unix format, actually, how it was

Comment: This worked for correctly me : _SELECT round(`time` / 0.4) * 0.4 Time1, AVG(dx), AVG(dy) FROM timegroup GROUP BY Time1;_ averaging over the expected number of results.

Comment: Thank you Paulf, it seems it works for me. And really fast

Comment: I wasn't sure if you wanted the rolling average result - but now I know what you want, I have posted my comment as an answer - if you care to mark it as such then anyone with a similar question can spot it as answered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't want a rolling average type result, then applying a bit of maths to the time column will allow for a query without a join.

This worked for correctly me :

```
SELECT round(`time` / 0.4) * 0.4 Time1, AVG(dx), AVG(dy) 
FROM timegroup 
GROUP BY Time1;
```

dividing the time by the required time division, round it to integer & then multiply back up by the time division - give all entries in that time block the same time. Then just group by Time1 & average the other two columns.

Comment: Any reason for the down vote after all this time after the answer was accepted - maybe a better method of solving the problem?